# How to pass array as parameter in javascript code function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am sending array of objects to print function but not working.

```
<script>
var items = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "rishi"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz"
}];
var output = "<button type='button' onClick='print(" + items + ")'>Print</button>";
document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML = output;

function print(data) {
    alert(data);
}
</script>

<body>

</body>

<script>
var items = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "rishi"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz"
}];
var output = "<button type='button' onClick='print(" + items + ")'>Print</button>";
document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML = output;

function print(data) {
    alert(data);
}
</script>

<body>

</body>
```

It should return array when I will click on print

Comment: Is there a reason why your code is repeated twice? Or is that just a formatting mistake?

Comment: Also is this code a mistake: document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML = output;
you should atleast use the first element of getElementsByTagName like so:
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = output;

Answer (score 0):

1. `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements, so that you should access the body element by index `[0]`
2. In order to see the content of objects in the alert try to convert them to strings using `JSON.stringify`

```js
var items = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "rishi"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz"
}];
items = JSON.stringify(items.map(JSON.stringify))
var output = "<button type='button' onClick='print(" + items + ")'>Print</button>";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = output;

function print(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with `document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML`. `.getElementsByTagName` doesn't return a single element, it returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which contains all body tags. Imagine if you passed `"p"` into the same method; it is possible that there are multiple `p` tags and thus you need to get a collection back, not just one single element.

Instead, you can use `document.querySelector('body')` which will return the first found element of `<body>`, which you can then use `.innerHTML` on.

Lastly, you'll need to stringify your `items` array such that it is preserved when you pass it into your `print` method

See example below:

```js
var items = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "rishi"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz"
}];

var output = "<button type='button' onClick='print("+ JSON.stringify(items) + ")'>Print</button>";
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = output;

function print(data) {
  console.log(data);
  alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is get the first item the [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns using `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`

Then call the function `print` passing items as the argument `onClick=print(items)`

```js
var items = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "rishi"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "xyz"
}];

var output = "<button type='button' onClick=print(items)>Print</button>";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = output;

function print(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`function print(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}`

Otherwise you get only data type shown `Object` in this case